# How to print the math a computer does for binary search

Tags: java, search, while-loop, binary

I'm working on a program that will ask the user to input a value between 3000-3100 and do a binary search and show how many comparisons it made.  Overall the search part of the program is working fine; however, my professor wants me to print the program doing the math.  For example, I need the program to show the computer doing the binary search math, and show the comparisons it takes for the program to find the inputted number.

I have a `comparisonCount` that I'm incrementing it when I do a comparison, but the results aren't what I think they should be. For example, my professor said if you input 3067 there should be 7 comparisons, but currently the program is saying 4, and the counter is saying 3.

Can you help me find the reason for the discrepancy?

Here's the code:

```
package binary.search;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BinarySearch
{
    public static void binarySearch(int[] array, int lowerbound, int upperbound,         int key)
    {
        int position;
        int comparisonCount = 1;   // counting the number of comparisons
        // To start, find the subscript of the middle position.
        position = (lowerbound + upperbound) / 2;
        //System.out.println();
        while ((array[position] != key) && (lowerbound <= upperbound))
        {
            comparisonCount++;
            if (array[position] > key)          // If the number is > key, ..
            {
                upperbound = position - 1;     // decrease position by one.
            }
            else
            {
                lowerbound = position + 1;    // Else, increase position by one.
            }
            position = (lowerbound + upperbound) / 2;
        }
        if (lowerbound <= upperbound)
        {
            System.out.println("The number " + key + " was found in array.");
            System.out.println("The binary search found the number after " + comparisonCount + " comparisons.");
        }
        else
            System.out.println("That number is not in this array. The binary search completed "
                + comparisonCount +  " comparisons.");


    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // Set up variables

        int arrLength = 100;
        Scanner inp = new Scanner(System.in);
        int[] num = new int[arrLength]; //Create array
        int repeat = 1;            //Boolean for repeat loop

        char yesNo;
        int upperLim = 3100;
        int lowerLim = 3000;

        //Populate array
        while (repeat == 1)
        {
            int value = 0;
            int valid = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < num.length; i++)
            {
                num[i] = i + lowerLim;
            }

            //Get integer from user
            do
            {
                System.out.print("Please enter a number between " + lowerLim + " and " + upperLim + ": ");
                value = inp.nextInt();

                if (value < lowerLim || value > upperLim)
                {
                    System.out.print("That wasn't a valid number. Please try again. \n");
                }
            }
            while (value < lowerLim || value > upperLim);

            //Run binary search
            binarySearch(num, 0, arrLength - 1, value);

            do
            {
                valid = 0;
                System.out.print("Would you like to rerun the program? Y for yes, N for no.\n");
                yesNo = (inp.next()).charAt(0);
                if (yesNo == 'Y')
                {
                    repeat = 1;
                    valid = 1;
                }
                else if (yesNo == 'N')
                {
                    repeat = 0;
                    valid = 1;
                }
                else
                    System.out.print("Not a valid response. \n");
            }
            while (valid != 1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: why dont you just add a counter and increment it when there is a comparison?

Comment: how would I go about doing that? declaring a counter and then using counter++ ????  Like I need it to print that it did (3100 -3000)/2 = 50, so 3047 would be at the lower half of the scale and so on until it finds the number.  Would a counter do that?

Comment: yup. int counter =0; then when you need to increment it, call counter++

Comment: for some reason the counter still isn't giving me the right reading.  My professor said if you input 3067 it should be 7 comparisons, currently the program is saying 4, and the counter is saying 3...

Comment: @JosephReed for 3067 the numbers compared will be 3049,3074,3061,3067.So there cant be 7 comparisons.

Comment: Added java tag, inferred from `import java.util.Scanner`. Tidied code formatting and a little rewording of the question.

Answer (score 2):

Seven iterations is the *maximum* that it would take to find a number in a set of one hundred. That's because `log2100` is somewhere between six and seven and you need to use the higher of those two values to be certain of finding it.

However, it may be less for certain *specific* values because of the way it works. Let's change your code so that it outputs what it's doing at each stage (just a few added outputs, sections marked with `//<<here` to `//<<`):

```
while ((array[position] != key) && (lowerbound <= upperbound)) {
    System.out.print(String.format(                        //<<here
        "Step %d, lo=%2d, hi=%2d, mid=%2d, [mid]=%4d, ", 
        comparisonCount, lowerbound, upperbound,
        position, array[position]));                       //<<
    comparisonCount++;
    if (array[position] > key) {
        upperbound = position - 1;
        System.out.println(String.format(                  //<<here
            "too high, hi:=%2d", upperbound));             //<<
    } else {
        lowerbound = position + 1;
        System.out.println(String.format(                  //<<here
            "too low,  lo:=%2d", lowerbound));             //<<
    }
    position = (lowerbound + upperbound) / 2;
}
if (lowerbound <= upperbound) {
    System.out.println(String.format(                      //<<here
        "Step %d, lo=%2d, hi=%2d, mid=%2d, [mid]=%4d, found!", 
        comparisonCount, lowerbound, upperbound,
        position, array[position]));                       //<<
    System.out.println("The number " + key +
        " was found in array.");
    System.out.println("The binary search found the number after "
        + comparisonCount + " comparisons.");
}
```

For example, if you're searching for `3049`, you'll basically find that straight away:

```
Step 1: lo= 0, hi=99, mid=49, [mid]=3049, found!
```

For your specific value of `3067`, it goes like this:

```
Step 1: lo= 0, hi=99, mid=49, [mid]=3049, too low,  lo:=50
Step 2: lo=50, hi=99, mid=74, [mid]=3074, too high, hi:=73
Step 3: lo=50, hi=73, mid=61, [mid]=3061, too low,  lo:=62
Step 4: lo=62, hi=73, mid=67, [mid]=3067, found!
```

Hence four iterations, as you're seeing. If you want to see the full seven iterations, you can just search for `3099`:

```
Step 1, lo= 0, hi=99, mid=49, [mid]=3049, too low,  lo:=50
Step 2, lo=50, hi=99, mid=74, [mid]=3074, too low,  lo:=75
Step 3, lo=75, hi=99, mid=87, [mid]=3087, too low,  lo:=88
Step 4, lo=88, hi=99, mid=93, [mid]=3093, too low,  lo:=94
Step 5, lo=94, hi=99, mid=96, [mid]=3096, too low,  lo:=97
Step 6, lo=97, hi=99, mid=98, [mid]=3098, too low,  lo:=99
Step 7, lo=99, hi=99, mid=99, [mid]=3099, found!
```